# Best way to create react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some time ago I created a front-end framework in html/css/jquery for dashboard creation for my company (something very complete) using classes like bootstrap.

Only, the new projects of my company will be done in react, and I need to adapt everything. I was thinking of simply importing the scss as several linked files, and use it simply by adapting some parts of the jQuery by the state react, especially for the onHover of the navbar and the header.

Well, this solution is extremely temporary because it implies each time to copy/paste the scss folder, it's not great, and my final goal will be to have a library of react components that you import with a simple npm install, like react bootstrap :

```
<Button {props} />

<Navbar>
  <Navbar.Brand.../>
</Navbar>
```

But also to be able to use the grid and the "simple" classes which are defined in the css of the library :

```
<div className="col-6">
   <div className="card">
   </div>
<div>
```

My explanation may not be very clear, but basically I'd like to create/use the main components with the lib, and use the scss classes of the lib...
Is this possible? If so, what would be the most suitable solution, knowing that I was thinking of making a library with storybook...

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar usecase.
You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library npm package.

It will reduce lot of your work.just focus on writing components/scss and check the dist same time with a test application provided by the package.

It works well!

Comment: I already looked at react-create-library quite quickly, but I had some problems, notably the scss compiled into css had prefixes to the classes, so I don't know if I could use them separately

Comment: You can use postcss and also define the rules like modules as false.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat as you, I created a set of components that I used in one project and needed to use in others without copying and pasting.  The best solution I have found so far is [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna).  It will not be easy and there is a big learning curve but after I spent some time on it I was able to get your desired result and have my own private npm packages that my team can install on projects without copying and pasting.  Since you want to use storybook this may [help](https://dev.to/shnydercom/monorepos-lerna-typescript-cra-and-storybook-combined-4hli).

Comment: Okay, I didn't know, I'll try to find out, thank you very much.